# Laravel - How to use other table except users table for login?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have written a PHP based Web Application several years ago in **Plain PHP**. Now for some reason, I want to upgrade that project in **Laravel**. But I face a problem when I want to Laravel default authentication *(which is done by php artisan make:auth)*.

Because, the old project uses **user_account** to store user info (username, password, and so on), but so far what I know, Laravel uses **users** table to store user information.

There is no way to rename **user_account** to **users** to solve the issue.

Is there any way to **user_account** in Laravel so that Laravel uses that table during **login**, **registration**, and so on..

- Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try with adding below line in your User Model(User.php).

```
protected $table = 'user_account';
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple and Sweet, 
Go to the User.php file (User Model)

```
protected $table = 'user_account';
```

Answer (score 1):

From Laravel Eloquent Model naming convention [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#defining-models):

By convention, the "snake case", plural name of the class will be used as the table name unless another name is explicitly specified. You may specify a custom table by defining a table property on your model:

```
protected $table = 'table_name';
```

So in your case you can go to the `User` model and override its default (plural name case) table binding and define:

```
protected $table = 'user_account';
```

I think this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have change in a number of places to achieve this goal.

#### Model

update user model from `app/User.php`, if you have not changed the default path

```php
protected $table = 'users';
```

#### Controller

on the `RegisterContoller` you need to update the validation rules, where it checks the unique email.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem like this. My problems is transfer data from Wordpress to java spring boot and problem is users table.So my solution is force to encrypt password in old project( Plain PHP) and used it on laravel project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to the USER model and rename the table name to the one you want, adding this line:

```
protected $table = 'user_account';
```

This way I dont think you shouldn't need to change much of code, and you will change the default "users" name to your custom one.

You should also be able to modify the fields in the "protected $fillable" array. However I'm not sure if all of this has some issue in the core code.